# useState not working - react native and sqlite

Tags: react-native, use-state

I'm new to React Native, sorry for mistakes on the code. I use React Native and SQLite (all expo).

My problem is that the "useState" does not save the data when entering the application, I have to update the app (Ctrl + s in Visual Studio Code) manually for it to save the data. I do not know why this is happening, can anyone tell me what the problem?

- The console shows "array []" initially and after updating the data appears inside the array

*edit my code :)*

console (first) ->

```
use effect 0 ------> Array []
use effect 1 ------> null
ENCONTRADO de tb_user o ID_user, username, nome_empresa --->  SORAIA
ENCONTRADO de tb_veic_user o ID_veic_uso onde kmf=null
```

console (second) ->

```
use effect 0 ------> Array [
  Object {
    "ID_veic_uso": 1,
  },
]
use effect 1 ------> null
ENCONTRADO de tb_user o ID_user, username, nome_empresa --->  SORAIA
ENCONTRADO de tb_veic_user o ID_veic_uso onde kmf=null
```

console (third) ->

```
use effect 0 ------> Array [
  Object {
    "ID_veic_uso": 1,
  },
]
use effect 1 ------> 1
ENCONTRADO de tb_user o ID_user, username, nome_empresa --->  SORAIA
ENCONTRADO de tb_veic_user o ID_veic_uso onde kmf=null
```

```
    const [dados, setDados] = useState([]);
    const [IDVeic, setIDVeic] = useState(null);

const findByUserna = (userna) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.transaction((tx) => {
                //comando SQL modificável
                tx.executeSql(
                    "SELECT ID_user, username, nome_empresa FROM tb_user WHERE username = ?;",
                    [route.params.paramKey],
                    //-----------------------
                    (_, { rows }) => {
                    if (rows.length > 0) {
                        resolve(rows._array),
                        console.log('ENCONTRADO de tb_user o ID_user, username, nome_empresa ---> ',route.params.paramKey);
                    }else {
                        reject("Obj not found: id=" + userna),
                        console.log('NAO ENCONTRADO de tb_user o ID_user, username, nome_empresa');
                    } // nenhum registro encontrado
                    },
                    (_, error) => reject(error) // erro interno em tx.executeSql
                );
            });
        });
    };
    const findByV = (cont) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.transaction((tx) => {
                tx.executeSql(
                    "SELECT ID_veic_uso FROM tb_veic_user WHERE username LIKE ? AND km_final IS NULL",
                    [route.params.paramKey],
                    //-----------------------
                    (_, { rows }) => {
                    if (rows.length > 0) {
                        resolve(rows._array),
                        console.log('ENCONTRADO de tb_veic_user o ID_veic_uso onde kmf=null');
                    }else {
                        reject("Obj not found: v=" + cont),
                        console.log('NAO ENCONTRADO de tb_veic_user o ID_veic_uso onde kmf=null');
                    }
                    } // erro interno em tx.executeSql
                );
            });
        });
    };




    useEffect(() => {
        findByUserna( route.params.paramKey )
        .then(
            findByV(route.params.paramKey)
            .then( 
                d => {
                    setDados(d)
                }
            )
        )
        .then(console.log('use effect 0 ------>',dados))
        .then( 
            dados.map(item => 
                setIDVeic(item.ID_veic_uso)
            ),
        )
        .then(console.log('use effect 1 ------>',IDVeic))
        
    },[])
```

Every time i save my file in vs code 1 useState works

Comment: In your "effect 0" line, log `d`, not `dados`.  React is weird and `dados` will NOT be updated after you call `setDados(d)`!  Not until it renders next time.

Also your "effect 1" line is in the wrong place.  You're passing 2 parameters to `then`.  It only expects one parameter.

Comment: It would be good if you quote exactly what your console output is, as it's not completely clear what console output you see.

Comment: @user2740650 thanks for the answer!! I changed my console and it still doesn't work. And I put 2 consoles in different places to see what was happening. And I noticed that it is showing the 'd', but it doesn't save in the 'data' (only saves the second time)

Answer (score 1):

The `setter` function of a `state` is asynchronous in react native. Thus, if you `console.log` the state object directly after setting it in the `useEffect`, it won't show the updated state.

However, a `state` change will trigger a rerender of your component, and it is guaranteed by the framework that the `state` will contain the updated value in the next render cycle.

We can verify that by putting the `console.log` outside of the `useEffect`.

```js
const [dados, setDados] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
            findByV(route.params.paramKey)
            .then( 
                d => {
                    setDados(d),
                },

            )
 },[])
console.log('data', dados)
```

We will notice two log messages. The first one is an empty array, which is the initial value of the state `dados`. The `useEffect` has an empty dependency array, thus it will be triggered exactly once if the component mounts. If we set a new state using `setDados`, it will trigger a new render cylce and the whole component renders again. This time the `useEffect` will not be triggered, but the `state` contains the new value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I use the const 'data' at the end of my code in a condition (if 'data' is not null, it renders certain component). And this it doesn't read the 'IDVeic'

```
 return (
            <Image
                style={fundoVeic.imageLogo}
                source={require('../../imagens/aaa.png')}
            />
            {IDVeic === null ?
            <View>...</View>
            :
            <View>...</View
            }
```